# Rails 4: Left join getting values of joined model

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, :primary_key => :mid, :foreign_key => :item_id
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie, :foreign_key => :item_id, :primary_key => :mid
end
```

Besides liking a movie the user can change some styling options of the liked movie via the **Like Model**, such as *expand* & *pin*.

```
# likes
+---------------------------------------+
| user_id | item_id | expanded | pinned |
|---------|---------|----------|--------|
|    1    |    1    |   true   |  true  |
|    1    |    2    |   false  |  true  |
+---------------------------------------+

# movies
+-----------------------+
|  title   | mid | year |
|----------|-----|------|
|  Avatar  |  1  | 2009 |
| Gladiator|  2  | 2000 |
|  Shrek   |  3  | 2001 |
+-----------------------+
```

In this example, the user likes the movies Avatar & Gladiator, while changing the movie states (`expanded`, `pinned`).

Now when I want to show all 3 movies in a view, I want to show the states of the movies the way the logged in user intended to. `(Avatar => expanded & pinned, Gladiator => pinned, Shrek => nothing)`

My solution so far was to load **all** movies, and then check querying the state of every movie... This resulted in far too many queries.

The desired table would look like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id | expanded | pinned | item_id / mid |  title   | year |
|---------|----------|--------|---------------|----------|------|
|    1    |   true   |  true  |       1       | Avatar   | 2006 |
|    1    |   false  |  true  |       2       | Gladiator| 2000 |
|   null  |   null   |  null  |       3       | Shrek    | 2001 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I understand that the query should be built up with a join via `includes`.

```
                                                                # ( 1 )
movies = Movie.includes(:likes).where(:likes => {:user_id => current_user.id }).references(:likes)
```

But when looping through the movies, I can't seem to get the data of the joined `likes` table, such as the `expanded` state:

```
movies.each do |m|
  puts m.expanded
  puts m.likes.expanded
end
# => undefined method `expanded' for #ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Like:0x007fae7ea51f48
```

I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that Rails is not very good in giving explanatory exceptions, but you should try understanding them never the less:

```
# => undefined method `expanded' for #ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Like:0x007fae7ea51f48
```

So, this error tells you that there is no method `expanded` where you think it should be.

Nr. 1 reason for this sort of things are bugs in your own code!

A good programmer always thinks about what he or she might have done wrong, so let's look at your code:

```
m.likes.expanded
```

Here we have an object of class `Movie`. From the code you provided, we can see that it `has_many` likes. That's why there is an `s` to the end. It's not `like` but `likes`. So it is a list of objects. In this case, it is a lazily loaded Array of objects joined from the database. In Rails, those are handled by `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`.

So you are calling `expanded` on an instance of that proxy object, but instead, you would like to call it on an instance of `Like`.

If you want to do that, you need to iterate over those as well, or pick the one that is relevant, which might be the like that the current user did.

Comment: You're my hero! My db structure implies that `m.likes` always contains 1 item, but blindly assuming Rails would automatically pick the first of the generated list was where I went wrong.

So using `m.likes.first.expanded` worked like a charm! :)

Comment: in this case, you should use a `has_one` relation

Comment: I realised after further testing that there were many likes belonging to the movie, not only one. So I ended up using:

`movies = Movie.includes(:likes).references(:likes)`. Lateron in the loop, I called: `like = movie.likes.where(:likes => {:user_id => current_user.id})`

Your answer helped me get there :)

Comment: it would be better to do this: `current_user.likes.where(id: movie.id)`. this is more intentional. and at best, put it into a method on the user, so you can ask `current_user.likes?(movie)`