# Rails Query for All Objects Through a Foreign Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models which have tables in my rails app (board and payment). I want to know which boards have a payment associated with them. Right now I have a has_one and belongs_to association setup between a payment and a board where the foreign key is a board_id in my payments table. So the payment belongs_to a board and a board has_one payment.

I want to get all of the board objects that have a payment ID associated with them. I know I can accomplish this by making a call to the payments table to get all the payments that have a board ID and then query for those boards, but I want to do this in one DB query. Is that possible? If so what does that query look like in rails?

Comment: If there is an association, how are there board objects that do not have a payment ID associated with them?

Comment: In rails it depends on how the association is setup. Right now I have a board_id in the payments table, but not a payment_id in the board tabl @Sinstein

Comment: btw, the first paragraph could easily be explained with code, with text only it's hard to visualize. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543490/rails-4-left-join-getting-values-of-joined-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either solve this with a subquery:

```
Board.where(id: Payment.select(:board_id).where.not(board_id: nil))
```

Or you can [inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/2235594) the two tables:

```
Board.joins(:payments)
```

Both resulting in one DB call

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help.

Comment: I just posted a second question in a similar realm if you have any insight http://stackoverflow.com/q/42455547/6162752

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy with inner join:

```
Board.joins(:payment)
```

Returns only boards with payment associated.

Of course you need `has_one :payment` in your `Board` class.

Comment: He said he had that set up: "Right now I have a has_one and belongs_to association"

Comment: Is there an easy way to invert this? I.e if you want to find Boards with no payments associated (either the payment_id is nil or the payment_id is stale... there is no Payment with that id)

Comment: @DanSharp yes, you need to use left join, i.e. `Board.left_joins(:payment).where(payments: { id: nil })`

Comment: Perfect! I was doing: `Board.where.not(id: Board.joins(:payment).map(&:id))` which works but has two queries and gets big if there are lots of boards with payments