# Identify Resource that Does Not Have a Payment Association with SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have an index page where I want to both show featured and standard boards. A featured board has has_one payment, a standard board does not.

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :board
end

class Board < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payment
end
```

So I can identify a featured board by joining the payments and therefor removing the standard boards.

```
Board.joins(:payment).where(category: category, confirmed: true)
```

Now I want to get the standard listings by doing:

```
Board.where(category: category, confirmed: true)
```

But this both returns the featured and the standard boards.

I'm looking for a way to get standard listings (boards that do not have a payment) and I just can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: see edited answer below

Comment: I find it rather impolite to specifically ask for my help and then ignore my answer...

Comment: @TheCha͢mp your answer led me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Board
  .joins("LEFT JOIN payments ON boards.id = payments.board_id")
  .where(payments: {id: nil})
```

I would highly suggest you [read this great blog post visualizing all different joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/). It also explains your use case: You first left join the boards with the payments and then filter out all board who *do have* a payment.

Comment: should be `joins("LEFT JOIN payments ON boards.id = payments.board_id")`

Answer (score 0):

The more compositional way of handling this is:

```
Board.references(:payment).where.not(payment: { id: nil })
```

You're encouraged to use scopes to your advantage. For example:

```
class Board
  scope :with_payments, -> { includes(:payment) }
  scope :featured, -> { with_payments.where.not(payment: { id: nil }) }
end

Board.featured # => SELECT * FROM boards JOIN payments ON payments.board_id = board.id AND payments.id IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new column in your Board model.

```
class AddPaymentToBoards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :boards, :payment, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Then change the create method of your Payment Controller to include this method from the Board model.

```
Board.rb

def payment_made
  self.update_attribute(:payment, true)
end
```

If you post the code that you use to create a payment I can help you more but it should be trivial.

Then you can create a scope

```
scope :payment_made, -> { where payment: true }
```

You will then be able to use `Board.payment_made` to return Boards where the payment Boolean attribute is true.